# How would I add a class type object to a vector?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vector, unreal-engine4

So I'm using Unreal 4 and Visual Studio to make a tic tac toe game. I've been instantiating blocks through a loop. That works. And now I want to add the new blocks to a vector so I can reference them when determining win conditions. The following screenshot has my code, and error. If anyone could help me out of this error, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you. [image]

Comment: You should paste your code instead of posting image. Your problem is that your vector doesnt accept pointer. You should solve your error by adding * in your vector declaration `std::vector<APuzzleBlock*> block;` in this way you will be able to store pointers in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a variable of type APuzzleBlock* (so, pointer) to an array that stores APuzzleBlock (no pointer)

You need to change the array to

```
TArray<APuzzleBlock*>
```